# OpenMP offloading in a dynamic library fails to compile

Tags: c++, c, gcc, openmp, offloading

I want to compile C code with OpenMP offloading and create a dynamic library  `libtest.so`.
When I use the following command:

```
gcc -fPIC -shared -fopenmp -foffload=nvptx-none="-fPIC" test.c -o libtest.so
```

I get this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccWnqb5o.target.o: relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.rodata' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

GCC version is 10.2.0.
I'm not sure what I do wrong here since `-fPIC` is included in the command. I wonder is it even possible to do what I want?

My `test.c` source just checks if the offloading works:

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void test()
{
  #pragma omp target teams
  {
    if (omp_is_initial_device())
      printf("on host\n");
    else
      printf("on target device\n");
  }
}
```

Comment: This was [the case](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=87833) for Intel MIC too. I'd guess a similar problem exists in the PTX offload library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spoke to the GCC developers and it seems to be a bug.  They seem to have it resolved for GCC 11, but the fix was not backported.  See https://gcc.gnu.org/g:a8b522311beef5e02de15427e924752ea02def2a for more information.

Comment: Thank you for the information and the link. I was able to apply the changes to the local build of GCC 10.2 on our compute servers, which is fine for my purposes right now. So I'll just wait for the GCC 11 release.